# Need a survey SaaS with immediate rewards for respondent

Tags: survey, saas, hosted

I am a PM and I would like to ask several specific users to provide feedback on our product.

We made a pretty long poll with several open questions, and I would like to incentivise users to answer all the questions by offering an immediate reward at the end of the questionnaire - for example a gift card, PayPal transfer and so on.

Requirements:

- I need the questionnaire's start page to clearly explain the reward and the requirements to receive it (e.g. fill the entire form).
- I need to be able to allocate user-codes to certain users so only they can fill in the questionnaire, unlike for example Google forms which is open to everyone.
- I need the software to reward the respondent by giving them store / gift credits **immediately** when they're done filling the questionnaire.

Does a service like this exist?